# ED-E turned hostile and I can't complete it's quest

Tags: fallout-new-vegas

I had ED-E and Cass as my companions for a while, but I decided to go solo so I left them waiting in my home. After some days they returned to their respective origin places.

I lost the perk provided by ED-E so I decided to recruit it again, but when I went to John Nash's store it turned hostile and attacked everyone in the room. I tried to let it unconscious by shooting but I killed it instead, hence failing it's related mission.

I've read around the Internet about this behavior, it happens if you left ED-E "abandoned" for too long. But I can't find a way to make it join me again and not being hostile. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is it possible to go back to an old save game file? Try that and bring here to the store to see what happens.

Comment: Sorry, I do have a save before leaving it behind, but I've done A LOT of quests now and I don't feel like re-playing a 30% of the game again. Any other solution?

Comment: Does it matter he killed everyone?  Is he attacking you?  If he's not, let the other guys die and talk to him normally.

Comment: @Nelson ED-E gets to kill John Nash and then attacks me

Answer (score 2):

If it is bugged there are a variety of console commands you can use to fix it:

> completequest [QuestID]
>
> addtofaction 1b2a4 0
>
> If you use the addtofaction command on ED-E you then need to use:
>
> stopcombat
>
> It will stop him from attacking.

The top command can be used to instantly complete the quest, provided you find its ID (list of ID's here:http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Fallout:_New_Vegas_quests) this is the ID for ED-E my love 001572e8 and I believe that is the quest you want.

The command below (addtofaction 1b2a4 0) will add ED-E to the players faction and make him friendly, but only stopcombat will stop him from attacking if he starts before you enter the command.